# Could I link project with different _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL than the libraries I use?

Tags: c++, debugging, linker-errors

I need to debug a program that handles a lot of data. The amount of data can't be reduced - the issue I'm after only occurs for a specific dataset.

Because of the amount of data handled, `_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL` starts to be a problem - in debug, the program is so much slower that it never completes. So I have set `_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL=0` and recompiled the project.

However, after recompiling the project, it's not compatible with the debug libraries. I am getting this error.

```
1>libboost_program_options-vc100-mt-gd-1_55.lib(options_description.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '2' doesn't match value '0' in ADProvider.obj
```

My question is: Is it possible to ignore this error and link the project regardless? As long as it runs, I don't care about possible consequences. I really need to debug the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason behind the different prebuilt Boost libraries is exactly that they are not binary compatible. In other words, an object of type `foo` might have a different layout in memory depending on those settings, e.g. a different size. For that reason, mixing is not possible.

Now, what you can do is to compile a variant without added diagnostics (i.e. without iterator debugging which is to catch a few cases of undefined behaviour) but still with debug symbols, so you can step through the code. I'm not sure of the current state, but last I looked those were not among those Boost libraries that are prebuilt by default.

Comment: Additionally boost is not he only library dependency. So I guess I'm out of luck. Any idea for an alternative solution?